# HLS.js required send http header

Tags: javascript, hls.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>

<video id="video" controls></video>

<script>
if (Hls.isSupported()) {
  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  const hls = new Hls();
  hls.attachMedia(video);

  hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
    hls.loadSource("http://foo.com/abc.m3u8");
  });

}
</script>


http header
id: 123
token: 456
```

I have a video required links to API, this API required to send id & token from HTTP header.

Does anyone know how to add HTTP header into HLS.js?

Answer (score 8):

try to use `xhrSetup`.

```js
const hls = new Hls({
  xhrSetup: xhr => {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('id', 1)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('token', 456)
  }
})
```

Comment: Will this work on Safari?