# Creation of a Java client app to to show hls streaming from external source with Basic Auth

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, media-player, basic-authentication, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to develop a simple java webapp with spring mvc that access an external HLS server that works like a proxy and streams more than a live video.
The external server (rtsp-simple-server, here the github page for those who are interested: https://github.com/aler9/mediamtx) has only the HLS protocol enabled and every source streams served is accessible from the urls: https://mediaserver.url:port/stream1, https://mediaserver.url:port/stream2, etc...
The streams are protected by the HTTP Basic Authentication.
My web app, deployed in my local machine need to access the streams, perform the authentication from the backend and show the video retrived in a web page.
For the streaming part, in the frontend, I use the streaming client hls.js.
My web page look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#video {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<video id="video" muted controls autoplay playsinline></video>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1.2.9"></script>

<script>

const create = () => {
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    var videoSrc = 'https://mediaserver.url:port/stream1/stream.m3u8';

    
    // always prefer hls.js over native HLS.
    // this is because some Android versions support native HLS
    // but don't support fMP4s.
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        const hls = new Hls();

        hls.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, (evt, data) => {
            if (data.fatal) {
                hls.destroy();

                setTimeout(create, 2000);
            }
        });

        hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
        hls.attachMedia(video);

        video.play();

    } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
        // since it's not possible to detect timeout errors in iOS,
        // wait for the playlist to be available before starting the stream
        fetch(videoSrc)
            .then(() => {
                video.src = videoSrc;
                video.play();
            });
    }
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', create);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way in Spring to injec the basic authentication header from the backend so that the hls client just need to call the stream and show it in the page, so that the login popup doesn't show up, nor do i need to write the credentials inside the streaming url in the web page?

I tried using webfilter, and I also tried to use the spring object RestTemplate.
With the last one i managed to retrice the m3u8 manifest but when I use it to retrive the segments thebrowser ask me to save them locally.

Many thanks in advance.

Here the HTML code I get from the server in the video tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<video id="video" muted controls autoplay playsinline></video>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1.2.9"></script>

<script>

const create = () => {
    const video = document.getElementById('video');

    // always prefer hls.js over native HLS.
    // this is because some Android versions support native HLS
    // but don't support fMP4s.
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        const hls = new Hls({
            maxLiveSyncPlaybackRate: 1.5,
        });

        hls.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, (evt, data) => {
            if (data.fatal) {
                hls.destroy();

                setTimeout(create, 2000);
            }
        });

        hls.loadSource('index.m3u8');
        hls.attachMedia(video);

        video.play();

    } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
        // since it's not possible to detect timeout errors in iOS,
        // wait for the playlist to be available before starting the stream
        fetch('stream.m3u8')
            .then(() => {
                video.src = 'index.m3u8';
                video.play();
            });
    }
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', create);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

-----------------------**UPDATES**--------------------------

I found the solution with spring.
Here the controller I've written to map the requests to the mediaserver.

```
@Controller
@EnableAsync
public class RTSPSSController {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RTSPSSController.class);
    // private static String LOCALHOST_PORT = "http://localhost:8080";
    private static String HOST = "https://media.server.org/";

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "cameras")
    public String cameras() {

        return "cameras";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "cameras/{camera}")
    public String camera(@PathVariable("camera") String camera) {

        return "cameras/" + camera;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "streams/{camera}")
    @ResponseBody
    public StreamingResponseBody getStream(@PathVariable("camera") String camera) 
            throws IOException {
                
        try {
            return stream (camera, "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
            // return null;
            return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).getBody();
        }

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "streams/{camera}/{media:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public StreamingResponseBody stream(@PathVariable("camera") String camera, @PathVariable("media") String media)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            // Retrieve restTemplate and inject the credentials for basic auth
            List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
            if (interceptors == null) {
                interceptors = Collections.emptyList();
            }
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>(interceptors);
            interceptors.removeIf(BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.class::isInstance);
            interceptors.add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("user", "password"));
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
            // restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("user",
            // "password"));
            ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                    HOST+ camera + "/" + media, HttpMethod.GET, null, Resource.class);

            InputStream st = responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream();

            // System.out.println(st.
            return (os) -> {
                readAndWrite(st, os);
            };
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
            // return null;
            return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).getBody();
        }

    }
private void readAndWrite(final InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(data)) > 0) {
            os.write(data, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

Now I can embed the streaming from the cameras served by the media server simply using the iframe tag as in the example down here:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Cameras</title>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe src="./streams/camera1/"></iframe>
 <iframe src="./streams/camera2/"></iframe>
 <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic auth is simply adding a header of the following form to an http request

Adding this header to the fetch is [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
   fetch(videoSrc,
       {
          headers: {
              "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64encoded(username + ‘:’ + password)
         })
        .then(() => {
            video.src = videoSrc;
            video.play();
        });
```

However, adding it to hls.js calls looks more [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647256/hls-js-required-send-http-header). Use authentication basic header, not id and token.

Put the Base64encoded(username + ‘:’ + password) into the page via the Java page renderer (Thymeleaf, JSP, outputStream) you are using in springboot.

Adding the auth header to the html5 video component used to be possible but it has been blocked because it is seen as a way to pirate videos. This [link](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1312) has a work around but its not simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to add the header to hls.js using xhrSetp.

Comment: Can i ask if there is a way to get it work also in iphone devides, since hls.js is not supported by theme? many thanks!

Comment: The _else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'))_ branch in the logic is to deal with the scenario, like iPhones that do not support hls.js.

Comment: Yes, of course, but how can I inject the basic auth in that case?

Comment: update answer with suggested code for vanilla fetch.

Comment: Thank you, I can get the manifest from the server but then I got a 401 when i try to stream the source (video.play()).

Comment: That depends on what sort of object video is. There must be a way to add the basic auth header to it. Add the html code that creates the element with id=“video” and any script src tags it depends on to the question.

Comment: Added to answer about blocked auth header setting on video. You could run your server as a proxy for the video site but that is difficult and requires capacity in your server to read and write the stream for the duration of the video (and is hard to implement) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277640/how-to-proxy-a-http-video-stream-to-any-amount-of-clients-through-a-spring-webse

Comment: I tried the last solution in Sping MVC, but i get the error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request. I realy appriciate your help!

Comment: you might need to play around with player.pause() and player.load() - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148998/the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-new-load-request